# Is there an option in Intl.NumberFormat() to automatically convert to bigger units?

Tags: javascript, format, internationalization

I'd like `Intl.NumberFormat()` to automatically convert between units from smaller to bigger ones based on common rules. I.e. a given number should be converted to between centimeters, meters, and kilometers in the output depending on how big the number is.

Code examples:

```js
const bytes = 1000000;
const transferSpeed = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',
  {style: 'unit', unit: 'byte-per-second', unitDisplay: 'narrow'}).format(bytes);
console.log(transferSpeed);

const days = 365;
const timespan = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',
  {style: 'unit', unit: 'day', unitDisplay: 'long'}).format(days);
console.log(timespan);
```

The output of these two calls is:

> 1,000,000B/s
> 365 days

In that case I'd expect this, though:

> 1MB/s
> 1 year

And one might want to define the threshold for when to convert to the next bigger unit. So it could be that the conversion should happen once the exact value is reached but also earlier, let's say at 90% of the next bigger unit. Given the examples above, the output would then be this:

> 0.9MB/s
> 0.9 years

Are there configuration options for the API to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not exactly a full answer to the question, but I thought I dropped this here in case it can help anybody.

Something close to this is actually possible with [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat), but it has some limitations. If you wanted to format byte values, for instance, you could:

1. Use the `compact` notation.
2. Use `unit` as your style, and provide `byte` as the unit.
3. Set `narrow` as `unitDisplay`.

With these options, the formatter will correctly convert from one unit to the other and, thanks to the `unitDisplay` value, it will display the unit of measurement as you would expect.

This is of course only usable with the few [supported units](https://tc39.es/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat/section6/locales-currencies-tz_proposed_out.html#sec-issanctionedsimpleunitidentifier) for which this makes sense, and it limits you to have the unit right next to value, even though that's usually what you'd want anyway. [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat#browser_compatibility) may also be an issue if you need to target older platforms.

Here's a sample.

```js
const byteValueNumberFormatter = Intl.NumberFormat("en", {
  notation: "compact",
  style: "unit",
  unit: "byte",
  unitDisplay: "narrow",
});

console.log(byteValueNumberFormatter.format(10));

console.log(byteValueNumberFormatter.format(200000));

console.log(byteValueNumberFormatter.format(50000000));
```

Comment: Great to see that it at least works partly! I think that answers my question. Hopefully, in the future this feature will be extended to cover all such use cases!

Comment: This works pretty well except it doesn't handle `gigabyte` or `petabyte` in Chrome or Firefox (not sure about Safari.) which is strange because they are valid units according to https://tc39.es/ecma402/#table-sanctioned-single-unit-identifiers

Gigabytes come out as `1BB` (billion bytes?)
and Petabytes come out as `1000TB`

It's really strange that Terabytes work, though.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature. You can see all possible options and methods in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat). Also, the [list of supported units](https://tc39.es/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat/section6/locales-currencies-tz_proposed_out.html#sec-issanctionedsimpleunitidentifier) for ECMAScript contains e.g. `byte`, `kilobyte` and `megabyte` as separate units.

I propose you implement this yourself or find a module that suits your needs. In the meantime, I searched the ECMAScript proposals but didn't find anything like it, so I filed an idea in the discussion board. Maybe it will catch on: https://es.discourse.group/t/automatic-unit-conversion-for-intl-numberformat/763

Comment: For bytes, I turned to [pretty-bytes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-bytes), which is small and uses NumberFormat in the background. It shouldn't be a great problem to adapt that implementation to support more units. Maybe I'll have a go at that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

By default `Intl.NumberFormat` displays gigabytes as 1BB (billion bytes) and petabytes as 1000TB.
Here is my workaround.

```js
const UNITS = ["byte", "kilobyte", "megabyte", "gigabyte", "terabyte", 'petabyte'];

const getValueAndUnit = (n) => {
  const i = n == 0 ? 0 : Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.log(1024));
  const value = n / Math.pow(1024, i);
  return { value, unit: UNITS[i] };
};

const bytePerSecondFormatter = (n) => {
  const { unit, value } = getValueAndUnit(n);
  return new Intl.NumberFormat("en", {
    notation: "compact",
    style: "unit",
    unit: `${unit}-per-second`,
    unitDisplay: "narrow",
  }).format(value);
};

console.log(bytePerSecondFormatter(10));
console.log(bytePerSecondFormatter(200000));
console.log(bytePerSecondFormatter(50000000));
console.log(bytePerSecondFormatter(30000000000));
console.log(bytePerSecondFormatter(70000000000000));
console.log(bytePerSecondFormatter(9000000000000000));
```